# Setting the background colour or a div failing when inside a fieldset

Tags: jquery, css

I'm hoping someone here can help me out, I'm relatively new to CSS and jQuery, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what I'm doing wrong in this case.

I've got a form, with labels, inputs and selects. I found a helpful tutorial showing me how to add a background colour to the parent div when I entered an input or select, which was removed when I moved on. The tutorial is here, http://css-tricks.com/improved-current-field-highlighting-in-forms/

The css I was using was really simple:

```
.curFocus {background-color: #fdecb2}
```

When used with some simple jQuery it worked wonderfully.

```
$("input").focus(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass("curFocus");
});
$("input").blur(function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("curFocus")
});
```

However, I then placed all my labels and inputs inside a fieldset, and now, my css no longer gets enabled.

This example works:

```
<div class="row">
  <label for="username">Your name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
</div>
```

This example does not work:

```
<fieldset class="align">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="username">Your name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

My CSS for the page is like this:

```
.align {
  border: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
.align label {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  padding-top: 0.6em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.align input {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}
.align select {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can re-enable the active field highlighting once more?

Comment: It should work, try to insert the css manually i.e: .row {background-color: #fdecb2} to the CSS. Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't work because DIV's are block elements, and you are floating the input/label elements within it. Because of these floats, the div doesn't have any height. Try adding this to your css-file:

```
.align div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Might solve it?

**edit**
For more info on clearing floats, check [this site of PPK](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it. I added that to the CSS and they now show up nicely, thanks!

Comment: Yeah floats and blocks can get really messy sometimes...Glad to help with that!

Answer (score 0):

think ti was them widths. You had 45% on the label and on the input, either use this or use yours and just set width to the fieldset. and remove the `padding-top: 0.6em;`

```
.align {
  border: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 1px;
    width:300px;
}
.align label {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.align input {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}
.align select {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
}
```

[take a look.](http://jsfiddle.net/caco/C8BFp/)